# Syntax error in VBA query expression in Access - Stumped

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm getting a message that there is a syntax error in a VBA query expression I have on a button in Access. Unfortunately, I just cannot figure out what the syntax error is. I'm pretty sure I'm using everything correctly. I'm sending this expression as the WHERE clause to a report being generated. The screenshot is below. Can anyone help?

The two strings that read `"tk"` are put into the expression from a couple input boxes.

[image]

My expression in text:

```
cond = "(((StrComp(""" & lower & """,Left([Location],2)))<=0) And ((StrComp(""" & upper & """,Left([Location],2)))>=0));"
stDocName = "rptMstrEquipListRange"
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , cond
```

According to www.balancebraces.com, the parentheses aren't the problem:
[image]

Comment: Is this expression not the same like StrComp(...) = 0 ?

Comment: Yes. This one in particular is, but as I stated above, the two strings that read "tk" are put into the expression from a couple input boxes.

Comment: Is that your entire expression?  If not post it.  It would be a lot nicer in text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work fine if you remove the `;` at the end. (Tested)